# I do not know how to get sublimelinter-html-tidy to work

Tags: sublimetext3, htmltidy, sublimelinter

I have sublime text 3, but after I installed sublimelinter-html-tidy through the 'Package Control: Install Package', nothing changed. I also have Emmit, Bracket Highlighter, Side Bar, and a few others installed on my Sublime 3, and they all do what they are meant to do. They work.  Only sublimelinter-html-tidy doesn't do anything, even though it is in my instaled packages.

Any help, or if someone could point me in the right direction, would be great.

Comment: Youv installed tidy as well?

Comment: If that is different than installing  sublimelinter-html-tidy, then no.  I didn't know there was more to it then just installing sublimelinter-html-tidy through Sublime.  What should I do?

Comment: If you are on OS X tidy should be installed by default, if not you will need to install it - that is what actually does the work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When installing new packages, I strongly suggest reading the documentation on [packagecontrol.io](https://packagecontrol.io). In the case of [`SublimeLinter-html-tidy`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-html-tidy), you will notice that there are two prerequisites: [`SublimeLinter3`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter) and `tidy`. First, though, please read through the [`SublimeLinter` docs](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org) to get an idea of what the plugin is, how it works, and how to set up specific linters. Make sure you read the [installation instructions](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html). Next, install and set up `SublimeLinter` via Package Control.

In order for `SublimeLinter-html-tidy` to work, you need to have `tidy` installed on your system. The instructions are in the docs I linked above. Once it is installed and you have verified your `PATH` as described in the SublimeLinter docs, you'll need to configure `tidy`. Documentation is [here](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/#docs).

Comment: I have read through all the links mentioned above. I already had 'SublimeLinter' and  Sublime-html-tidy packages installed before asking my question.  I don't see anything dealing with Windows 7 for downloading 'Tidy'.  My problem now is to find out where I can download 'Tidy'.

Comment: @thinnling the SublimeLinter-html-tidy docs, which I linked in my answer, include a link to [this site](http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?HTML_Tidy_for_Windows), where you can download a precompiled binary of `tidy` for Windows. Make sure you put it in a directory that's in your `PATH`, or add its directory to your `PATH`.

Comment: ok, cool.  Downloaded the Tidy and libtidy.  How would I find where my Path would be?  What folder could it be in?

Comment: I have put both files in what I believe is my PATH: my main Sublime Text 3 folder. I still don't know how to check if this is my PATH, though. Still not working.

Comment: @thinnling go to `Start -> Settings -> Control Panel -> System` and click on the `Advanced` tab. Click the `Environment Variables` button, then under `System Variables` select `Path`, then click `Edit`. Add the directory where you put `tidy.exe` and `libtidy.dll`. Save and close out, then restart Sublime.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, Matt.  Your instructions were very clear and concise and you have helped me so much.  Thank you for being so patient and helpful to me. :)